# Force a function to exit

Tags: python, function, exit

I've tried everything from using `return` to `sys.exit` to `SystemExit` and it doesn't work.

I have a `main` function, that runs the 1st function; at the end of the 1st function it runs the 2nd function; at the end of the 2nd function it runs the 3rd function; and after that it asks whether I want to run the program again or exit. No matter the choice, it always returns me to `main`.

Is there a way to force close a function inside a function inside a function inside a function?

edit:
example:

```
def main(RPNlist):
    some code here
    #this function converts a .txt file to a list, wich is a math operation
    y=list
    print(list)
    return(func2(y))
def func2(y):
    some code here
    #this function converts the operation to reverse polish notation
    z=RPNlist
    print(RPNlist)
    return(function3(RPNlist))
def func3(RPNlist):
    some code here
    # this solves the RPN operation
    a=answer
    print(a)
    choice=input("do you want to exit?(Input y to continue or n to exit): ")
    if choice=="y":
        return(main(x))
    elif choice=="n":
        #here's the part where I need to exit

#I think this may be the issue, but is the only way I found for the whole program to run
global RPNlist
RPNlist=[]
main(RPNlist)
```

Comment: paste you code here please

Comment: it's REALLY long... 425 lines... it's a RPN calculator

Comment: @sshashank124 I tried it,  it stills return me to the main function

Comment: @sshashank124 he did mention using `sys.exit`

Comment: Step through with a debugger, calling exit should exit regardless. The exit code is never being reached.

Comment: Try looking at this. It calls the function five times recursively and then quits on the fifth time http://repl.it/fSK. Notice the print(2) never executes since you will not see any output

Comment: Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows others to recreate the issue.

Comment: Just use an if statement that calls the main in the main if a certain input is received. Otherwise, nothing will happen as there is no code to execute.

Answer (score 0):

It's really depend of your code.

```
return value
```

It will always quit your function. The problem is not here. Maybe the return is not called (if it's in a if). Maybe you have a loop, in that case, use a break to exit the loop. Let the app close by itself. When there is no method call remaining, the app will exit by itself. Just get out of the loop. You can also put a condition for the loop if it's an infinite loop, put a boolean in it then turn the boolean to false.

It's hard to help without your code, you need to show your code if you want better answers.